# ping: cannot resolve db1: Unknown host

Tags: mysql, macos, unix

I'm using macOS version : Catalina (10.15.6).

I'm trying to connect the mysql instances to create an InnoDB cluster.
When i try to ping to check the connection, it gives me the error "cannot resolve db1:Unknown host"

**"ping localhost" works fine.
But the changes made including new hosts are not reflected**

I have edited my hosts file in /private/etc

Contents of the hosts file :

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
192.168.z.xyz   db1
192.168.x.xyz   db2
::1             localhost
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
"hosts" 11L, 238C
```

P.S : .z.xyz is simply an example for any IP addresses i try!

Comment: Do we assume `z.xyz` is you obfiscating ip addresses that are actually not accessible from the internet and therefore the obfiscation is unnessary or did you actually code `z.xyz`?

Comment: Yeah i simply obfuscated it, because i tried several ips and nothing worked! .I did not code it as z.xyz, i just gave it as an example. :)

Comment: Try adding : order hosts, bind into your /etc/resolv.conf file to see if that fixes it (even temporarily).

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389305/how-can-i-modify-the-hosts-file-on-macos-catalina

Comment: it doesnt work, tried both! :(

Comment: macOS is extremely picky about the format of the /etc/hosts file. See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951379/etc-hosts-ignored-in-mac-el-capitan-10-11-5) for how to make sure your entry is properly formatted.

Comment: Yeah @GordonDavisson  i checked the format and it is properly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the file got damaged/corrupted.

Solution :
**Creating a new hosts file** worked : [here](https://superuser.com/a/1191214)